# Помогите с часами, пожалуйста

Tags: wordpress

У меня сайт сделанный на word press, на сайте часы, которые синхронизируются с временем на компьютере с которого заходится на сайт. То есть время устанавливается на сайте исходя из времени, того что на компьютере. Цель: сделать так, чтобы часы на сайте отображались в независимости от времени часов на компьютере, а синхронизировались с общем мировым временем - конкретно города Екатеринбурга.
Возможно ли как-нибудь выводить определённое время? Например Екатеринбургское. Это нужно брать время по Просто у юзера не всегда на компьютере стоит точное время, а мне хотелось выводить точное Екатеринбургское время, несмотря на то какое время стоит у юзера, который заходит на мой сайт.

Помогите мне пож, вот код который стоит у меня на сайте.
это между в конце /body вставлено. работает норм, только синхронизацию сделать с общем временем (Екатеринбурга)

```js
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clock() {
var d = new Date();
var month_num = d.getMonth()
var day = d.getDate();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var seconds = d.getSeconds();

month=new Array("января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня",
"июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря");

if (day <= 9) day = "0" + day;
if (hours <= 9) hours = "0" + hours;
if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if (seconds <= 9) seconds = "0" + seconds;

date_time = "Сегодня - " + day + " " + month[month_num] + " " + d.getFullYear() +
" г.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
if (document.layers) {
document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
}
else document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
setTimeout("clock()", 1000);
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
clock();
</script>
```

то что в css думаю не надо?

Answer (score 1):

Для решения вашей задачи, нужно брать время с сервера вашего приложения (со стороны php), переводить его во время Екатеринбурга и выводить на сайт.

Клиентская сторона - не лучший источник времени:

- время на клиенте может быть сбито
- часовой пояс может стоять неверно, а время - верно (если у пользователя руки кривые). Тогда, вычисляя по этому времени и поясу время в Екб, вы получите погоду на Марсе.

Comment: помогите пожлуйста как это сделать Для решения вашей задачи, нужно брать время с сервера вашего приложения (со стороны php), переводить его во время Екатеринбурга и выводить на сайт.

Comment: как взять время с сервера , что прописать? куда и какой код?

Comment: Как здесь http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42252/get-wordpress-current-date-time

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(); // локальное время пользователя
```

что бы установить конкретное, например серверное нужно использовать синтаксис:

```
var d = new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

как именно его передать скрипту - сильно зависит от места шаблона, где расположен данный блок кода. Если поддерживаются php иньекции, то выглядело бы так:

```
var d = new Date(<?=date("Y");?>, <?=date("m");?>, <?=date("d");?>, <?=date("H");?>, <?=date("i");?>, <?=date("s");?>);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37609/discussion-on-answer-by-iosp----).

Answer (score 0):

Зачем такие сложности? Установите на сайте WordPress в админпанели время Екатеринбурга. В нужном месте на странице спросите это время у WordPress:

```
$time = current_time('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Запишите в элемент #doc_time.